# Insert bar graph for Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, chart-web-part

I am trying to insert a bar graph for my Sharepoint list but I can't get it to display for some reason. The list is called "GPS III Cause Codes" and has two columns. Column 1 has a name and column 2 has a value from a dropdown choice menu. How can I change the code below so that it counts the number of occurrences for each value in column 2 and creates a bar graph?

Example data:

```html
|Column 1  |  Column 2 
---------------------------
| Bob      | Option 1
| Dave     | Option 2 
| Tom      | Option 1 
| Dan      | Option 5
| Jason    | Option 1
```

Could someone let me know where I am missing something?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var splistitems;
var seriesarray = new Array();

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetChartData, "sp.js");

function GetChartData() {
   seriesarray = [];
   var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var splist = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('GPS III Cause Codes');
   var splistquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   splistitems = splist.getItems(splistquery);
   currentcontext.load(splistitems);
   currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, GetChartDataSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, GetChartDataFail));
}

function GetChartDataSuccess(sender, args) {
   var splistitemcount = splistitems.get_count();
   if (splistitemcount != 0) {
      var splistitemenumerator = splistitems.getEnumerator();
      while (splistitemenumerator.moveNext()) {
         var currentlistitem = splistitemenumerator.get_current();
         var itemname = currentlistitem.get_item("Title");
         var count = currentlistitem.get_item("Cause Code Count");
         var seriesitem = {
                           name: itemname,
                           data: [ count ]
                       };
         seriesarray.push(seriesitem);
      }
      DrawChart();
   }
}


function GetChartDataFail(sender, args) {
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function DrawChart() {
        fruitChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart-container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Cause Code Trends'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Discussion', 'Document/Procedure Request', 'Data Request', 'SpaceX response/clarification', 'Identification','Documentation Error', 'Missing Testing Results', 'Out of Tolerance Results'] 
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of Requests'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                false
            },

            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: seriesarray
        });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example demonstrates how to count the number of occurrences of values in column:

```
var counts = {};
items.get_data().forEach(function(item){
      var fieldVal = item.get_item('<fieldName>');
      counts[fieldVal] = (counts[fieldVal] ? counts[fieldVal] + 1 : 1);
});
```

**Complete example**

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(renderChart, "sp.js");

function renderChart(){
      var listTitle = 'GPS III Cause Codes';
      var properties = ['Title','Cause Code Count'];
      getListData(listTitle,properties,function(items){
            var counts = {};
            items.forEach(function(item){
                 var val = item.get_item('Cause_x0020_Code_x0020_Count');
                 counts[val] = (counts[val] ? counts[val] + 1 : 1);
            });

            var series = []; 
            items.forEach(function(item){
                  var countPerName = counts[item.get_item('Cause_x0020_Code_x0020_Count')];
                  series.push({name :item.get_item('Title'), data : [countPerName] });
            });
            drawChart(series);
      },
      logError);
}

function getListData(listTitle,propertiesToReterieve,success,error){
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var qry = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
   var expr = 'Include(' + propertiesToReterieve.join(',') + ')';
   var items = list.getItems(qry,expr);
   ctx.load(items);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
             success(items.get_data());
         }, 
         error);
}





function logError(sender, args) {
   console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}




function drawChart(data) {
        var fruitChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart-container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: data
        });
}
```